# How do I repeat the loop to give a list of answers for A?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Im creating a loop for my university project. I need A to return an array of the sums.

```
An=np.array([51,101,201,301,501])
t=100
MM=9
Mi=1    
rep=5
for agentcount in np.arange(0,5): #count over agents
    N=An[agentcount]
    for M in np.arange(Mi,MM+1):
        for crep in range(1,rep+1):
        win=(np.random.rand(M,1)>0.5).astype(int) #winning record as 1/-1 #winning record
        s1=(np.random.rand(2**M,N)>0.5).astype(int) #random strat
        s2=(np.random.rand((2**M),N)>0.5).astype(int) #alternative strat
        payout=np.zeros([2,N]) #empty payout record
        for ct in range(1,t+1): #timesteps
            cc=np.abs((1+ np.dot((2**(np.arange(0,M))),win))) #pick next strat
            nex1=s1[cc-1,:]
            nex2=s2[cc-1,:]
            nexts=[[nex1],[nex2]]
            for cn in np.arange(0,N+1): # choose better strat
                if payout[0,cn-1]>payout[0,cn-1]:
                Next=nex1
                else:
                Next=nex2
            A=(np.sum(Next)/N)
```

---

I want the ct section of the loop to run ct times and therefore return a 1xct array for A.
I have tried using the built-in sum function and also using notation A[ct]=
Thank you

Comment: create an `AList = []` before the `for ct..` and after calculating A do `AList.append(A)`. Anyways I would recomend you to re-think your code, never is a good idea to use anidated fors...

Comment: This will just create a list with the same value ct times. The loop needs to run ct times giving ct different values for A

Comment: so what do you need? I cant understand the problem you are having or what you really want